# Asp.net vb content hiding behind HTML image when scrolling

Tags: asp.net

Actually My problem is i want to rotate the image when a button click occurs(HTML img and HTML Button), i already done that with help of jQuery , but now after rotating the image the content is hiding behind that Rotated image when scrolling.i hope u understand my problem, please give me any suggestions,thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a z-index to the image or the content (A low or minus z-index on the image will put it behind, or a high z-index on the content will bring it to the front). Create a CSS class:

```
.BringToTheFront{ z-index: 1000 };
```

or

```
.SendToTheBack{ z-index: -1000 };
```

And then assign the class to the image / content. If this doesn't work, you may need to use jQuery to assign the CSS to the element after it has rotated.

```
$('#MyElement').css('z-index', 1000);
```

or

```
$('#MyElement').css('z-index', -1000);
```

If you are using z-index elsewhere on your page, you may find 1000 isn't enough.

Dan